# Why is シャワー used with 浴びる?

Tags: verbs

I'm a little confused as to why it's 浴びる as opposed to する. In nouns like 掃除 or ゲーム, the verb used is する. Can anyone clarify?

Comment: This is not an answer but シャワーする, though not the best, is understandable for sure and probably even grammatically correct/used by some people. A native speaker could perhaps tell how strange it feels

Comment: ^ "Take a shower" の意味で「シャワーする」っていうのはちょっと変な気がします・・普通は「シャワーを浴びる」「シャワーにかかる」とかじゃないですかね。。「シャワーする」は、どこか特定の部分とかに「シャワーをかける」って意味に聞こえるような・・

Comment: @Chocolate 「シャワーにかかる」って初耳でした（笑）知恵袋に質問がある… https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12170497127

Comment: "*As opposed to する*"? I wonder if there is a language in which you actually use a noun "shower" with an auxiliary verb "do" to mean "take a shower". There are languages that have a separate verb for it, but doing a shower sounds like sprinkling something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture 浴びる should evoke in your head is "something pouring on to your body."

シャワー is literally water pouring on to you, so 浴びる is the most natural verb to go with it. Another example would be 日光(sunlight)を浴びる, and here you can also picture sunlight pouring down on you from the sky.

する is the most generic verb like "do", and as such it does cover a wide variety of cases. But again just like the English word "do", there's also a lot of cases where this verb just wouldn't do it. Examples include 医者にかかる, 車を運転する, 水を飲む, and so on.

Comment: If one evokes an image of "something pouring on one's body", one will have a hard time figuring out why that "something" is a direct object of the action. I find it more convincing to evoke an image akin to "walking the street", "swimming the river", "abiring the sun". Say, "entering a shower"